# Dividing the image and getting coordinates

Tags: java, graphics, image-processing

I have an image with yellow background containing a random figure as shown in figure:

[image]

The random figure is divided by black lines into image pieces. Now each piece can be represented separately as a square containing that piece image with transparent background.

My question if it possible to find the coordinates of each piece algorithmically in the original image?

I am writing this application in Java.

I don't have much idea about the graphics. If its possible then please elaborate little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use [connected component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Component_Labeling) on the binary image (threshold your current image).

I used MATLAB to threshold the image, and run a labeling algorithm. Then I used region properties to find the centroid of each connected component (which are the image pieces you need). The following is the labeled image with the black stars representing the centroid of each piece:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the images look mostly like what you have here

```
Loop    
  Find a Red pixel
     If found
        flood fill red to non-red at this point, remembering region
        create output image from this region
     else
        You are done
```

Comment: But how can I get the coordinates of each square region?

Comment: If (0,0) is top left of image, bounds of the region is top-left (Min X of region, Min Y of region), bottom-right (Max X of region, Max Y of region)

Comment: Hi, your algorithm looks good . Can you point me to some sample code or how to remember region while doing floodfill.

Comment: In your case, a region is just a set of pixels.  During flood-fill, if you color a pixel, add its coordinate into a set collection.